# Eclipse sluggish/slow on Linux dual monitor

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, java, eclipse, nvidia-quadro

I know there are severeal questions that ask how to improve the response behaviour of eclipse. However, most of the answers suggest to disable openjdk and install oracle or increase (or sometimes, decrease?) the available memory for the jvm. However in my case, Eclipse is only sluggish on one of two monitors.

I have 2 24'' full hd screens, one of which is rotatetd 90 degrees. On the horizontal screen, Eclipse runs and reacts fine, but on the rotated, there is a noticable lag between a command, key stroke or even scroll action and the visible result. This is worst if the window is large or maximized, if I resize the window to maybe 1/4th of the screen, it also runs fine.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.3 lts, running nvidia-346 drivers on a Nvidia Quadro NVS 310 video card. I'm using Oracle Java  (build 1.8.0_66-b17).

There is no spike in CPU activity when this happens, and I have no other java programs on this machine. Is my card video too just slow, or can I improve the responsiveness of Eclipse somehow?

Thanks!